# File upload using ajax request

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to upload image, using ajax. i am sending request like this:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveReferral", "ReferralIM", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    OnSuccess = "OnSuccessReferralSent"
}, new { id = "frmReferral", onSubmit = "OnControlMapping(this);" }))
{
```

}

if i send request like this:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveReferral", "ReferralIM", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "frmReferral", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
   {
```

File uploaded successfully, but i want to use ajax ,Please help me how i should do for file uploading with ajax.
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I am not using MVC BUT if you want to use $.ajax then here it is...

```
$('.file-uploadID').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var fileInput = $('.file-uploadID');
            var fileData = fileInput.prop("files")[0];   // Getting the properties of file from file field
            formData.append("file", fileData); // Appending parameter named file with properties of file_field to form_data
            formData.append("user_email", email); //adding email address as parameter if you have
            $.ajax({
                  url: '/FileUploadHandler.ashx',
                  data: formData,
                  processData: formData.processData,
                  contentType: formData.contentType,
                  type: 'POST',
                  success: function (data) {
                        var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
                        if (obj.StatusCode == "OK") {
                              alert("file upload done");
                        } else if (obj.StatusCode == "ERROR") {
                              alert("file upload error");
                        }
                  },
                  error: function (errorData) {
                        $('.result-message').html("There was a problem uploading the file. Please try again.").show();
                  }
            });
      });
```

## Handler

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
  {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Expires = -1;
        var email = context.Request.Params["user_email"];
        var fileData = context.Request.Files["file"];
        try
        {
             var result =  UploadImageToServer(email, fileData);
              context.Response.Write(result);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
              context.Response.Write("error while uploading file to the server, please try again.");
        }
  }
```